# Why does my lcd console turn off if I let the imx6 board stay idle for 10 minutes?

Tags: yocto, imx6

I'm new to imx6 and yocto bsp and on exploring I found that the lcd console goes off after exactly 12 minutes. There seems to be no mention of this in the source code in yocto if there are no functions that turn off the display how could it go off?

I did some digging and found that yocto provides a wait mode which is meant to save power. I function I found in  cpuidle-imx6sl.c as below but there is no mention of disabling lcd

static int imx6sl_enter_wait(struct cpuidle_device *dev,
                            struct cpuidle_driver *drv, int index)
{
        int mode = get_bus_freq_mode();

```
    imx6_set_lpm(WAIT_UNCLOCKED);

    if ((mode == BUS_FREQ_AUDIO) || (mode == BUS_FREQ_ULTRA_LOW)) {
            /*
             * bit 2 used for low power mode;
             * bit 1 used for the ldo2p5_dummmy enable
             */
            if (psci_ops.cpu_suspend) {
                    psci_ops.cpu_suspend((MX6SL_POWERDWN_IDLE_PARAM | ((mode == BUS_FREQ_AUDIO ? 1 : 0) << 2) |
                                            (ldo2p5_dummy_enable ? 1 : 0) << 1), __pa(cpu_resume));
            } else {
                    pwr_ctrl_off();
                    imx6sl_wfi_in_iram_fn(wfi_iram_base, (mode == BUS_FREQ_AUDIO) ? 1 : 0,
                                    ldo2p5_dummy_enable);

            }


    } else {
            /*
             * Software workaround for ERR005311, see function
             * description for details.
             */
            imx6sl_set_wait_clk(true);
            cpu_do_idle();
            imx6sl_set_wait_clk(false);
    }
    imx6_set_lpm(WAIT_CLOCKED);

    return index;
```

}

I expect to find a function in the kernel source that disables lcd and also has a timer that measures exactly 10 minutes for lcd off. where can I find these?

Comment: I forgot to mention the lcd comes up on pressing the power button does that mean the function also supports interrupt handling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably seeing the console blanking timeout after 10 minutes, which turns off the display. To check the timeout value:

```
$ cat /sys/module/kernel/parameters/consoleblank
600
```

To disable it permanently, add `consoleblank=0` to the kernel commandline. For example by editing your U-Boot environment.

You can find the code, that is responsible for this in `drivers/tty/vt/vt.c`.

Comment: Yes I looked into that you are absolutely correct so does that mean the cpu wait mode doesn't do anything to save power?

Comment: Actually I don't know in which way the CPU wait mode is used by Linux on i.MX6SL. But this is totally unrelated to the LCD blanking.

Comment: I've spent a veryyyyyyyyy long time trying to find a dirty bug in lvds drivers and stuff... Thanks a lot...!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this command to force screen to get out of the sleep mode :

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/graphics/fb0/blank
```